# Where are Firebase CustomClaims stored

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I've searched around and have come up blank. I can't figure out where OAuth2 claims are actually stored in Firebase. I refer here to the claims that I can set via `SetCustomUserClaimsAsync` and get (through the returned user) via `GetUserAsync`. I guess I was imagining being able to manage that data via some browser page, as well as via code, but perhaps by design this is not possible?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom claims currently don't have a UI in the Firebase console.  Feel free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for that.  Right now, you will have to write code to find the contents using the APIs you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! If the feature doesn't exist yet, that would explain my success (or lack thereof) in finding it. I have filed a request.